# How to use sed to replace numbers with parenthese?

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have a file test.txt contains many lines like the following:

```
hello:123: world
hello:783: world
hello:479: world
......
```

How to use `sed` command to replace the lines as follows?

```
hello:(123, 0): world
hello:(783, 0): world
hello:(479, 0): world
......
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

How do you like this one? I hope it is what you needed.

```
sed -e 's/\([0-9]\+\)/(\1, 0)/g'
```

**Test**

```
echo "hello:123: world
hello:783: world
hello:479: world" | sed -e 's/\([0-9]\+\)/(\1, 0)/g'
```

**Result**

> hello:(123, 0): world
>
> hello:(783, 0): world
>
> hello:(479, 0): world

Comment: this will fail if first column has `he123llo`, use `sed -e 's/\(.*:\)\([0-9]\+\)\(:.*\)/\1(\2, 0)\3/g'` instead

Comment: `echo "he123llo" | sed -e 's/\([0-9]\+\)/(\1, 0)/g'` works just as intended for me with the result "he(123, 0)llo"

Comment: Assuming OP wants to process text after `:`

Comment: You're right, now I see what you mean.

Comment: dude, this `-e` gave me headache in Mac, it was `sed -E`

Comment: `-r` here... (GNU sed)

Answer (score 3):

POSIXly:

```
sed 's/[0-9]\{1,\}/(&, 0)/' < file
```

Would replace the first occurrence of a series of one or more (`\{1,\}`) decimal digits with `(&, 0)` (where `&` is the text being replaced) on each line.

Some `sed` implementations have a `-E` option for using extended regular expressions (ERE) instead of basic ones (BRE), when you can use `+` in place of `\{1,\}`. `-E` might make it to the next version of the POSIX specification:

```
sed -E 's/[0-9]+/(&, 0)/' < file
```

Some `sed` implementations like GNU `sed` support `\+` as a BRE alias for `\{1,\}` though that's not portable/standard.

To use perl regular expressions which are becoming a new de-facto standard for regular expressions, you can use... `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/\d+/($&, 0)/' < file
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming input has `:` separated text and 2nd column needs to be changed:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS=":" } {$2 = "("$2", 0)"} 1' ip.txt
hello:(123, 0): world
hello:(783, 0): world
hello:(479, 0): world
```

Or, with `perl`

```
$ perl -F: -lane '$F[1] = "($F[1], 0)"; print join ":",@F' ip.txt
hello:(123, 0): world
hello:(783, 0): world
hello:(479, 0): world
```

Comment: Damn, I was just about to post `awk` one. Cool +1

Comment: ha, I actually tried it out seeing your comments as a learning exercise :)